# BootStrap-css declaring class inside address or another class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap and i am unable to declare  a class inside an id in css....also unable to declare class inside another class in css...heere i just gave my id problem...

```
    <!--html-part-->

<section id="homeicon" class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
        <h2>Save Your Time</h2>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, totam accusamus veritatis fugiat animi pariatur.</p>
      </div>
 css
#homeicon{
  .far{
    font-size:30px;
  }
```

Comment: It's not valid CSS to nest rule sets. Try writing `#homeicon .far {}` instead, or use a tool like SASS

Comment: Thanks for replying bro.... i just tried it as you said..still not working :/

#home-video .dark-overlay{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%

}

Comment: Try creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to help without it.